# Cluster Matrix from CSV Pandas DF Scipy

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scipy, cluster-computing

I am fairly new to pandas and completely new to scipy clustering. I have a pandas dataframe that I read in using pd.read_csv that is a matrix that looks like this (the values represent distance from each other:

```
    dog cat squ mea  che 
dog  0  .6  .5  .3    .2 
cat  1   0  .3  .7    .9
squ .6  .3   0  .3    .8    
mea .1  .1  .3   0    .9
che .4  .3  .4  .7     0
```

I want to cluster my matrix using scipy to ultimately create a dendrogram with hierarchal/agglomerative clustering and I tried

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
Z = linkage(df)
```

But I get hit with this value error immediately and am not sure how to proceed

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'dog'"
```

I know I am not clustering these matrices correctly, but am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works nicely for me, as long as the first column is the index. When loading your dataframe, load it like this, specifying `index_col=[0]` to specify the first column as the index:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0])
```

---

```
df

     dog  cat  squ  mea  che
dog  0.0  0.6  0.5  0.3  0.2
cat  1.0  0.0  0.3  0.7  0.9
squ  0.6  0.3  0.0  0.3  0.8
mea  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.0  0.9
che  0.4  0.3  0.4  0.7  0.0

Z = linkage(df)
Z

array([[ 0.        ,  4.        ,  0.678233  ,  2.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  3.        ,  0.69282032,  2.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  6.        ,  0.71414284,  3.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  7.        ,  0.93808315,  5.        ]])

dendrogram(Z)

plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: my goodness! I overlooked specifying the first column as the index. Thanks so much, really excited to finally see my data visualized. Will definitely be more attuned to the importance of specifying the index while reading in a matrix in the future.